# Issue with binary tree, C code, using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, binary-tree

I am trying to write a simple tree program in C, after a long long time :) but am stuck at the code where I add more nodes to my root node

Here is the code snippet:

```
  struct node* root;
  struct node* new_node;

  // Add a node
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  new_node -> left = NULL;
  new_node -> data = 934;
  new_node -> right = NULL;

  // Mark this as root
  root = new_node;

  // Add a node
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  new_node -> left = NULL;
  new_node -> data = 967;
  new_node -> right = NULL;

  // Make this left node of root
  root -> left = new_node;

  // Add a node
  new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  new_node -> left = NULL;  // This line is the problem
  new_node -> data = 612;
  new_node -> right = NULL;
```

The line which is causing issue is marked with comment.
The moment I make it NULL, the data 967 becomes 0.

However, if I put the new_node code in a function and call

```
root = new_node(934)
root -> left = new_node(967)
root -> right = new_node(612)
```

That works fine. I tried gdb on my code but could not understand why it would happen

Comment: Well, it looks like an overwrite issue, yes?  So, it's probably pointers and their targets, mallocs etc yes?  So, as a debug check, printf out 'sizeof(struct node*)' to see how much memory you are allocating.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, that is what I did after I received the answer below. Also I forgot that I was working on a 64 bit machine while using gdb, so calculated the size of my struct as 4 byte fields, mentally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

should be:

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

everywhere. Another possiblity is `new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));`.

You need to allocate an entire node to point to, not just a pointer to a node.

Since you didn't allocate enough memory for a node, you got undefined behavior when writing to the fields of the node, which in your case caused it to overwrite existing data.

Comment: Ah !! Silly me. Thanks for pointing that out. So instead of assigning 24 bytes to my new_node it was just 8 bytes